# System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2 error

Tags: linq

I am getting this error : System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[ConsoleApplication1.Person,<>f_
_AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]]

When I try to do this in a console application :

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID;
    public int IDRole;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}



class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
        new Person() {ID = 1, IDRole = 1, LastName= "Anderson",
        FirstName = "Brad"},
        new Person() {ID = 2, IDRole = 2, LastName= "Gray",
        FirstName = "Tom"}
        };

        var query = from p in people
                    where p.ID == 1
                    select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName };
       Console.Write( query);
       Console.ReadLine();

}}
```

Comment: You need to iterate the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the query

```
foreach(var q in query)
    {
      Console.Write( string.Format("{0} {1}",new []{ q.FirstName ,q.LastName }));
    }

   Console.ReadLine();
```